# Vectorizing ode in R using purrr

Tags: r, ode, purrr

I'm trying to solve a number of permutations initial conditions for an ODE using purrr.

I have the following information stored in a data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(deSolve)

flow.data <- tibble(Unit=c(rep("MSS",times=11),rep("CS",times=3)),
                Size=c(400,750,1200,1600,2400,3000,3600,4500,
                      6000,7200,10000,(1700*60/500),(4000*60/500),
                      (6600*60/500)),
                Product=Size/60*3.786,
                Feed=Product*.85,
                Blowdown=Feed*.15,
                Vol=c(74,106,163,275,353,492,603,
                      772,1340,1417,1800,7,18,26),
                Ca=c(rep(10000,n=14))
                )
```

I've set up the ODE solution as follows, and it works when I plug in the variables:

```
odefunction <- function(h,q,ca,v){
   g <- .5  #L/min
   h <- h*3.785  #Feed gal/min converted to L/min
   q <- q*3.785 #Blowdown gal/min converted to L/min
   v <- v*3.785 #Vol gal converted to L

   parameters <- c(h=h,q=q,v=v,f=ca)
   state <- c(ca=0)
   times <- seq(0,50,by=1)

   funs <- function(t,state,parameters) {
         with(as.list(c(state,parameters)),{
       dca <- (h*f/v)-(q*ca/v)
       list(c(dca))
         })
   }

   out <- ode(y=state,times=times,func=funs,parms=parameters)
  }
```

For example,

```
res <- odefunction(118,18,10000,1370)
```

produces:

```
> head(res)
     time        ca
[1,]    0    0.0000
[2,]    1  855.6803
[3,]    2 1700.1916
[4,]    3 2533.6797
[5,]    4 3356.2886
[6,]    5 4168.1601
```

I'm trying to get results using pmap (from purrr) to map the list to the odefunction.

```
test <- pmap(list(flow.data$Feed,flow.data$Blowdown,flow.data$Ca,flow.data$Vol),odefunction(h,q,ca,v))
```

I'm expecting to get a nested tibble with the solution to the ODE ala for the row using flow.data, I would have :

```
MSS 400 25.2 21.5 3.22 74 10000 tibble...
```

What I'm getting is:

```
Error: Can't convert a `deSolve` object to function
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

<error>
message: Can't convert a `deSolve` object to function
class:   `rlang_error`
backtrace:
-purrr::pmap(...)
-purrr:::as_mapper.default(.f, ...)
-rlang::as_closure(.f)
-rlang::as_function(x, env = env)
-rlang::coerce_type(...)
-rlang:::abort_coercion(.x, .to)
 Call `summary(rlang::last_error())` to see the full backtrace
```

Any thoughts about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try with just `pmap(list(flow.data$Feed,flow.data$Blowdown,flow.data$Ca,flow.data$Vol),odefunction)`. You don't need to add the arguments. I would try myself, but idk where the `ode` function comes from.

Comment: Separate issue, but using `select` can make your `pmap` call a little less cluttered. `pmap(select(flow.data, Feed, Blowdown, Ca, Vol), odefunction)`

Comment: Perfect!  The first makes it work and the second makes it easier to read.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't get that error, just `object 'h' not found`. RyanD's first suggestion works, and for the second one, for me I had to map the variables, `pmap(select(flow.data, h = Feed, q = Blowdown, ca = Ca, v = Vol), odefunction)`, although `?pmap` makes it looks like OP's function would work if the variables were mapped, but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: I spoke a little too soon on the second.  I tried it and had some issues.  Either way, the first works well.  Thanks again.